# When does Ionic Router trigger a render (including offscreen Routes)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework to build a react app. At the very top of my component tree sits an IonReactRouter.

Now I need to pass data between routes and have to carefully design when which Component should render. So I added logging code and was surprised to see many unexpected renders. It seems that Ionic Router is never unmounting a Route and is wasting renders on Components that are off-screen.

To reproduce the behaviour, create a sample Ionic app (this is the sidemenu template) with this code:

```
ionic start --start-id SpOfzzZnR
```

and add some logging to the Page rendering:

```
console.log('rendered '+name +" at " +new Date().getUTCSeconds());
```

The key parts of this example are an app with a Menu and a Router:

```
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
    <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
      <Menu />
      <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
        <Route path="/page/:name" component={Page} exact />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/page/Inbox" exact />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonSplitPane>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

and a page that reads its name from a route parameter:

```
const Page: React.FC = () => {

  const { name } = useParams<{ name: string; }>();
  console.log('rendered '+name +" at " +new Date().getUTCSeconds());

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonMenuButton />
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>{name}</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
    </IonPage>
  );
```

When switching between routes, it always renders both the old and the new Route:

```
rendered Trash at 46 Page.tsx:10 # currently viewing Trash, clicked on Spam
rendered Spam at 46 Page.tsx:10
rendered Spam at 48 Page.tsx:10 # currently viewing Spam, clicked on Trash
rendered Trash at 48 Page.tsx:10
```

Why does it do this?

Comment: does this still happen. if so can you post the code for menu as well